# Import from .sql file Oracle SQL Developer excluding duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have exported a table from one database using Oracle SQL Developer as .sql file and want to import it into another database that has exactly the same table, but the problem is that some entries appear in both tables.

Is there a way when importing using Oracle SQL Developer to exclude entries that already exist in the destination table?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways:

1. You can use the SQLLDR tool or external table to load
2. You can load your sql file into the database and then remove duplicates.

Let's use this file:

```
data.sql
insert into test_table (id) values (1);
insert into test_table (id) values (1);
insert into test_table (id) values (2);
insert into test_table (id) values (2);
insert into test_table (id) values (2);
insert into test_table (id) values (3);
insert into test_table (id) values (3);
```

SQLLDR:
At first you create integrity constraints for your table for example:

```
SQL> create table test_table ( 
  2    id number(10) primary key
  3  );

Table created.
```

Then create a control file:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE data.sql
INTO TABLE test_table
(
id position(37:37)
)
```

After running you will see:

```
SQL> select * from test_table;

    ID
----------
     1
     2
     3
```

And the bad file (This lines were rejected because of the integrity violation):

```
data.bad
insert into test_table (id) values (1);
insert into test_table (id) values (2);
insert into test_table (id) values (2);
insert into test_table (id) values (3);
```

You can generate the external table using this control file, so I don't show you how to use it.

Load and remove duplicates:

Let's recreate the `test_table` table:

```
SQL> create table test_table (
  2    id number(10)
  3  );

Table created.
```

Using SQL Developer load your sql file and check the content:

```
SQL> select * from test_table;

    ID
----------
     1
     1
     2
     2
     2
     3
     3

7 rows selected.
```

and then remove duplicates:

```
SQL> delete test_table where rowid not in (select min(rowid) from test_table group by id);

4 rows deleted.

SQL> select * from test_table;

    ID
----------
     1
     2
     3
```

I believe there is a way more ways to complete your tasks, I showed only ways that came in my head right away.

Comment: Thanks! I understand version 2 better so I am going to try and solve my problem that way, will let you know how I get on later today.

Comment: OK so I tried to export and then import table using .sql file, export went smoothly but when importing I ran into errors and decided to abandon this approach. I then tried exporting .cvs file and did import with using csv option, again got some errors, but when chose to ignore them, I half succeeded. By half I mean some part of the table in one database was transferred to another table on another database, but not all. I find all this very strange as I am using automatically generated files by same version of Oracle SQL Developer. I am obviously doing something wrong...